# Why is bluetooth support one of the default packages in "Base" when doing an RHEL/CentOS server install?

Tags: centos, redhat, kickstart, packages

This is an issue that has bugged me for a long time - why would the default *server* installation of RHEL?CentOS include *desktop/laptop* packages like bluetooth?

When using kickstart, I will usually start with the `Base` packages set, and then customize from there.

However, it seems counter-intuitive to me to put user-centric packages on a server - why is this done?

Comment: Is there anything about a server that precludes the use of a wireless keyboard or mouse?

Comment: You mean you don't use bluetooth for server-to-server communications?

Comment: It's so you can bluetooth tether to your phone to give you Internet access.

Comment: @GeraldCombs My desk is more than 32 feet from the server room. Also, people kept tripping over the VGA cable strung down the hallway. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there are Red Hat developers/product managers here, I don't think you'll get an answer justifying this.  It's especially perplexing in the "Server" product.

Either way, it's trivial to remove the packages in `%post`, or Kickstart with `%packages --nobase` and start with a minimal installation and build up your package list from there.

Erase packages in %post that match `yum search bluetooth`:

```
yum erase bluez* gnome-bluetooth* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Comment: I know the `%post` can be used - and I do, but it's still a bizarre annoyance

Comment: I agree 100%... I just don't think you'll find an explanation here. Only workarounds. G'luck!

Answer (score 2):

I find the server release to really be more of a "NO GUI" release.

You'll find other stuff in there too. (irda for example)

It seems reasonable that you might want to install a NO GUI install on an old laptop, so bluetooth might still be nice to have.

You can try installing just 'Core' and not 'Base'.
%packages --nobase
(but that may not be possible anymore)

You can also try building a custom kickstart that only includes the packages you really need.

Comment: Server most definitely includes the GUI and is even installed by default. The main difference between the Desktop and Server is the supported hardware. Server also provides cluster administration/GFS packages, while Desktop provides more typical desktop software like Evolution, Finch, Thunderbird, OpenOffice.org, etc... RHEL Server is probably overkill for a an old laptop at ~$350/year.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the 'Server' install is a graphical desktop + server software. In other words it is largely a super set of desktop. It makes perfect sense for bluetooth support to be in a desktop since bluetooth accessories are getting more and more popular. In any case, I would expect that the performance penalty for having it is minimal while the convenience gain for things like home media servers is very big.

If you are in a situation where you want the fastest/most tuned Red Hat install, you should not be installing server anyways. You should be starting with a minimal install and adding in only the things that you need/use.

Comment: It's not a super set since Desktop includes packages which are not in Server. http://serverfault.com/questions/370482/why-is-bluetooth-support-one-of-the-default-packages-in-base-when-doing-an-rhe/370486#comment377228_370487